# How to find the particular solution of $y'' + 4y = t^2 $?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If I would have a trial solution 
$ c_3 \cdot t^2 $ (with c_3 as a constant)

$2 \cdot c_3 + c_3 \cdot t^2 = t^2$ (which would only be true if t =0 and $c_3 =0$)

If I would have the trial solution $ c_3 \cdot t^3 $

I would get $ 6 \cdot c_3 \cdot t + 4 \cdot c_3 t^3 = t^2 $ and have the same problem.

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: try $y = at^2 + bt + c$ where $a, b, c$ are constants.

Answer (score 1):

$y_p={1\over 4}(t^2-{1\over 2})$ is such that $y_p^{''}+4y_p=t^2$. If you want to be systematic look for a polynomial solution

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^Na_kt^k$$

One has for the second derivative

$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^Nk(k-1)a_kt^{k-2}$$

and so the equation rewrites as

$$4a_Nt^N+4a_{N-1}t^{N-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{N-2}\left((k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}+4a_k\right)t^k=t^2$$

And the only solution is $a_k=0$ for $k\neq 0,2$  $a_2={1\over 4}$ $a_0=-{1\over 8}$

Answer (score 0):

## Hint:

your assumed solution not right so this problem is happend.

The particular solution should be assumed
$$y_p=at^2+bt+c$$
$$y'=2at+b$$
$$y''=2a$$
$$2a+4(at^2+bt+c)=t^2$$

now, it is easy to find the cofficients